# Why is my wordpress shortcode not following closing tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

This is my plugin:

```
add_shortcode('twitter', function($atts, $content) {

    // print_r($atts); die();
    if (!isset($atts['username']) ) $atts['username'] = 'att';
    if ( empty($content) ) $content = 'Follow me on Twitter';

    // shortcode_atts 

    $content .= '<div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serf">';
    $content .= '<h2 style="color:orange">My Plugin here!</h2>';
    $content .= '<a style="color:blue" href="http://twitter.com/' . $atts['username'] .'">' . $content .'</a></div>';

    return $content;
});
```

I'm expecting just a div with

```
<div>
    <h2>My Plugin here!</h2>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/envatowebdev">Please follow me everybody!</a>
</div>
```

But instead I'm getting the following:

[image]

```
<div>
    <h2>My Plugin here!</h2>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/envatowebdev">Please follow me everybody!</a>
    <div>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/envatowebdev">
            <h2>My Plugin here!</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I think it's because Wordpress is reading my closing `[/twitter]' tag as a new shortcode:

```
[twitter username="envatowebdev"]Please follow me everybody![/twitter]
```

But the same problem isn't happening for the author of [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/wordpress-plugin-development-essentials/) I'm following, and I am in HTML text edit mode so I'm not sure why this is going on.

Link to post: http://attapi.com/new-post/

`[twitter username="envatowebdev"]Please follow me everybody![/twitter]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function testf($atts, $content = "") {           



        // print_r($atts); die();
        if (!isset($atts['username']) ) $atts['username'] = 'att';
        if ( empty($content) ) $content = 'Follow me on Twitter';

        // shortcode_atts 
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serf">
            <h2 style="color:orange">My Plugin here!</h2>
            <a style="color:blue" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo $atts['username']; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></a></div>
        </div>
        <?php

        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works... not sure what `ob_` means, but thanks :D